# I called a method but it doesn't print

Tags: java

i'm a beginner, I barely know anything, I tired to do some classes and just mess around with methods, but for some reason the method wont print, also I'm really bad with arrays :(

main class :

```
public class Employees {

static Employee[] array =new Employee[3];
static int i=0;


 public void insertEmployee(){

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("please fill in the information :");
    System.out.println("name :");
    String Name=keyboard.next();
    System.out.println("ID :");
    long ID=keyboard.nextLong();
    System.out.println("Salary :");
    double Salary =keyboard.nextDouble();

    Citizen s2 =new Citizen(Name);

   Employee E= new Employee(ID,s2,Salary);
   array[i]=E;

}

public  void main(String[] args) {

  Employees m1=new Employees();

  for ( i=0; i<3;++i){
    Employees c1=new Employees();
    c1.insertEmployee();
  }

  System.out.println("*****");
  for (i=0;i<3;++i){
      array[i].print();
  }
 }
}
```

second class :

```
public class Employee {

private Citizen employeeInfo =new Citizen();
private long employeeID;
private double employeeSalary;

Employee(long employeeID,Citizen employeeInfo ){

    this.employeeID=employeeID;
    this.employeeInfo=employeeInfo;

}

Employee(long employeeID,Citizen employeeInfo, double employeeSalary){

    this.employeeID=employeeID;
    this.employeeInfo=employeeInfo;
    this.employeeSalary=employeeSalary;

}

void print(){
    if (employeeSalary==0){
        employeeSalary=-1;
    }
    System.out.println(employeeID+"-"+employeeInfo.getCitizenName()+"-"+employeeSalary);

 }
}
```

and last one:

```
public class Citizen {

private String citizenName;
private long citizenID;

public Citizen(){

}

public Citizen(String Name){

    this.citizenName=Name;

}
public Citizen(String citizenName,long citizenID){

    this.citizenName=citizenName;
    this.citizenID=citizenID;

}

public String getCitizenName(){

    return citizenName;
}

public long getCitizenID(){

    return citizenID;
 }
}
```

thank you :)

Comment: Which method `doesn't print`? give us more information

Comment: you need to ask an specific question

Comment: too much code that is not relevan, wich method must print what in which class???

Comment: the insterEmployee method, sorry for not pointing it out

Comment: @banana: Define what you mean by "doesn't print".  What *does* it do?  When you step through this code in a debugger, where *specifically* does the behavior differ from what you expect?  "Here's a bunch of code, it doesn't work" isn't usually an answerable question.

Comment: when i called the method insterEmployee in the main method, when i run the program, nothing comes up

Comment: @banana: Then this is an opportune time to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger, which is as valuable a tool as the code itself when writing software.  Start with a Google search on something like "how to debug Java".  There are IDEs, such as Eclipse or NetBeans, which have tools built-in to make this easy.  With a debugger you can step through the code, literally line by line, as it executes.  You can observe the runtime behavior and runtime values of your variables.  With this you can narrow down the specifics of the problem.

Comment: Your main method has to be static

Comment: i have netbean, there's no error in the code

Comment: @banana: `"there's no error in the code"` - Well, if nothing is wrong, then clearly there's no problem to solve here.  On the other hand, if something *is* wrong, then you're going to have to drop the assumption that your code is correct and without errors.  You can also start by reducing the space of the problem.  Start with a much simpler program and get that working.  Add individual pieces of functionality one at a time.  When it stops working, you've found your bug.

Comment: What he said ^^^^!

Answer (score -1):

It has to be `public static void main(String[] args)`. The `static` is important

Comment: still doesn't print :(

Comment: @banana Just tested the code (with corrected main method) and it is printing and scanning everything fine

Comment: it doesn't for me :\

Comment: oh okay thank you, i copy paste it in a new sheet and it worked, i dont know why, but thanks!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's usually a better idea to not answer vague questions like this at all and flag them.